# how do i deal with this error from my connection string?

Tags: c#

when i try to update my database from the terminal this is the error that am getting

C:\Users\stycs\attempt2\SolarCoffee\SolarCoffee.Data>dotnet ef --startup-project ../SolarCoffee.Web database update
Build started...
Build succeeded.
System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: solar.dev (Parameter 'keyword')
at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder.GetProperty(String keyword)
at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder.set_Item(String keyword, Object value)
at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder.set_ConnectionString(String value)
at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder..ctor(String connectionString)
at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlDatabaseCreator.Exists()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.Exists()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String contextType)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String contextType)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)

Keyword not supported: solar.dev (Parameter 'keyword')

my migrations went through without any error. here is a sample of my code

appsettings:

```
{
   "Logging": {
     "LogLevel": {
         "Default": "Information",
         "Microsoft": "Warning",
         "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
        }
    },
   "ConnectionStrings": {
      "solar.dev": "Host=localhost;Port=5432;Username=solardev1;Password=solar123; Database=solardev1;"
       }
}
```

the following is from the startup:

```
services.AddDbContext<SolarDbContext>(opts =>
        {
            opts.EnableDetailedErrors();
            opts.UseNpgsql("solar.dev=ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection");
        });
```

thank you in advance for the help

Comment: Why are you passing the parameter you are passing to UseNpgsql? One look at the documentation helps you see you are doing something wrong: https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/

Comment: changed my code and used this one instead '{
                opts.EnableDetailedErrors();
                opts.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("solar.dev"));
            });' and it works now.

Comment: please upvote the comment if it was helpful